# How to prefix an area code when dialing with iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I just moved to Idaho, and here everyone has the same area code (208 for the whole state). Unfortunately I still have my old phone number. So when someone texts or emails me a phone number they never include the area code. When I try to dial it with my iPhone I get an error from AT&T that I need to first dial the area code.

If I type the area code, and then try to paste the number in that will replace the area code. I am not able to get a edit point anywhere by the end of the phone number in the keypad screen. The only options I have found is to paste the phone number in notepad or somewhere that allows editing, add the area code, then copy and paste that into the keypad. Either that or cache the phone number outside the phone and then re-enter it manually.

Is there some way to tell the iPhone to assume 208 is the area code when none is provided, or at least a way to edit a phone number from the keypad to add an area code?

(I realize there is probably an app for that, but it seems like a pretty common thing that should be supported by the iPhone without an extra app step.)

Comment: I don't know about the app (which I doubt, unless it's an app that changes the Address Book), but the iPhone can't do that "pretty common thing". I travel fairly often from Europe to the US and I have to change the 001 (to call TO the US) with 011 to call FROM the US. Annoying :)

Comment: @MartínMarconcini Oh bother.

Comment: Martin, The + features in phone numbers for precisely that reason. Store your phone numbers instead as +1 123 456 7890 and you'll find they work wherever you are in the world. The + takes the place of the local international dialing prefix.

Comment: http://www.howtocallabroad.com/qa/plus-sign.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you could do it either. Maybe you could use an app on your PC to modify the address book for all numbers without an area code and that is in Idaho? Then sync this to the iPhone… Have you contacted AT&T to see if there is something they can do?

Comment: AT&T and iPhone both say it is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be a perfect solution, but what I do is store all numbers in my contacts with 1 and the area code. That way it dials appropriately no matter where I am (it doesn't change the billing details - a local call is still a local call, whether it includes the area code or not).

Also, maybe this is a carrier specific thing, but any texts I receive from numbers not in my contacts show up with the full +1(123)456-7890 formatting.

Answer (score 2):

An app called Launcher allows to dial from a notepad, which is editable.
That function was already included in the PalmPilot based phones. On that point the iPhone is inferior.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. Out of nowhere, my Verizon iPhone stopped being able to dial 7 digit numbers. I too live in small area where 7 digit numbers are common.

I searched but no answers. I turned off my phone and no fix.

Then, I restarted my phone by holding the power and home button together for 20 seconds until the Apple logo is shown, and *it went back to normal!* I knew it was something simple.